# optimistic and pessimistic locks

Tags: php, codeigniter

Working on my first php/Codeigniter project and I’ve scoured the ‘net for information on locking access to editing data and haven’t found very much information.

I expect it to be a fairly regular occurrence for 2 users to attempt to edit the same form simultaneously.

My experience (in the stateful world of BBx, filePro, and other RAD apps) is that the data being edited is locked using a pessimistic lock—one user has access to the edit form at the time. The second user basically has to wait for the first to finish.  I understand this can be done using Ajax sending XMLHttpRequests to maintain a ‘lock’ database.

The php world, lacking state, seems to prefer optimistic locking. If I understand it correctly it works like this:  both users get to access the data and they each record a ‘before changes’ version of the data.  Before saving their changes, the data is once again retrieved and compared the ‘before changes’ version. If the two versions are identical then the users changes are written.  If they are different; the user is shown what has changed since he/she started editing and some mechanism is added to resolve the differences—or the user is shown a ‘Sorry, try again’ message.

I’m interested in any experience people here have had with implementing both pessimistic and optimistic locking.  If there are any libraries, tools, or ‘how-to’s available I’m appreciate a link.

Thanks

Comment: .NET DataSets also use Optimistic Concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, CodeIgniter has no support of locking rows.
If you want to implement optimistic locking, you should add a version column or timestamp column that is you must change on each update/insert. Put the version column into a hidden field in your forms. Then before each update, add a where  clause like :

```
$this->db->where('version',$editedVersion);
```

or

```
$this->db->where('timestamp',$editedTimestamp);
```

And then you should check that the update correctly updated 1 rows..

```
$this->db->where('id',$editedId);
$this->db->update('tablename',$data);
$rowsAffected = $this->db->affected_rows();
if ($rowsAffected == 0) {
    /* Data changed by other user, update failed */
} else {
   /* updated successfully */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the InnoDB storage engine you can obtain row level exclusive locks via SELECT FOR UPDATE statements.

[SELECT ... FOR UPDATE  and SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE Locking Reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

[InnoDB Lock Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html)